# Get the maximum number in Java

Tags: java

I need to get the maximum of three ints, but my code will not give output when the second number is less than zero.

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=in.nextInt();
    int b=in.nextInt();
    int c=in.nextInt();
    int max;
    if(a>b){
        if(a>c)max =a;
        else max =c;
      } 
    else{
        if(b>c)max=b;
        else max=c;
  System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

It passed the test of other situations. Could you tell me why it happened?

Comment: Try storing the values into a `List`. Then by using `Collections.max()` to get the largest value.

Comment: You need to move your System.out.println so its outside of the else.

Comment: Thanks all of you...I know what is my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your print statement is inside of the else block, so it will only get executed if it goes to the else branch. Move it to outside of the else block.

```
...
else {
    if(b>c)
        max=b;
    else
        max=c;
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because of where you have your println statement. Its in the second conditional, you want it to be outside the if statements.

```
public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=in.nextInt();
    int b=in.nextInt();
    int c=in.nextInt();
    int max;
    if(a>b){
        if(a>c)max =a;
        else max =c;
    } 
    else{
        if(b>c)max=b;
        else max=c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest writing separate method

```
public int max(int a, int b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
}
```

and call it like

```
max(a, max(b, c));
```

The code is lot cleaner this way

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.max()` on a `List` which stores your int values.

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a= in.nextInt();
    list.add(a);
    int b= in.nextInt();
    list.add(b);
    int c= in.nextInt();
    list.add(c);
    System.out.println("Largest: " + Collections.max(list));
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Input the numbers into a array instead of three separate variables. then you can use this method :

```
public int getLargest(int[] nums){
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    if(nums.length == 0)
        return -1;
    for(int i : nums){
        if(i > largest)
            largest = i;
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: This returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for an array of length 0.

Comment: Fixed, i sort of assumed most people wouldn't be sending blank arrays

Comment: I would have assumed an Exception would be raised instead of returning a number that doesn't exist in the array. I won't lead you on a wild goose chase though.